# How do i properly populate a dropdown list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to populate  my dropdown list I had it working by entering  each variable into the array manually however I would like to be able to add the the array using a loop.

Sorry I'm new to javascript

```
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>

var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = new Array(51);
var firstyear = ( new Date().getFullYear() ) - 17;
var temp = 0;

for ( var i = 0; i < 51; i++ ) {
    temp = firstyear - 1;
    options.push( temp );

    alert( temp );
}
alert ( options );

for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ ) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild( el );
}
```

Comment: This is not Java; it's JavaScript. They are totally different languages.

Comment: sorry meant javascript

Comment: You can use Jquery. newSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: index,
                                text: "Text"

Comment: Here's a fun test I did 9 years ago investigating ways to do this in then-current browsers: http://phrogz.net/tmp/selectmanipulation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>

<script>
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = new Array();
var firstyear = (new Date().getFullYear()) - 17;
var temp = firstyear;

for(var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
    options.push(temp);
    temp--;
    }

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Beware though, depending on the speed of the browser, you might get some race conditions where the `select` is undefined.

Comment: You should be setting `el.text`, not `el.textContent`, as the text property reflects the text attribute, not *textContent*. And there are many browsers in use that don't implement *textContent*, but they all implement the *text* property.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close but you're missing a ")" character.

You have:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 51; i++ {
```

It should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
```

To note: debug output for loops is often best done using console.log instead of alert. It'll show up the Javascript console on any browser but be careful about leaving them behind, as it'll break IE8 (maybe even 9+?) if they're left in there and the console is not presently open!

Answer (score 0):

There are several small errors in your code:

- You javascript code is run before the elements are created on the page, so `document.getElementById("selectNumber");` is undefined when it is called. You need to enclose your code in a function that will be called once the document has been fully created.
- If you initialise your array with `var options = new Array(51);` and then use `options.push(...)`, you will have 50 empty values, and then the values you added. You need to change your initialisation to `var options = new Array();`
- You forgot a `)` in `for(var i = 0; i < 51; i++ {`
- You need to change `temp = firstyear - 1;` to `temp = firstyear - i;` otherwise you will fill your array with 50 times the same value
- One loop is enough to achieve this

Here is an updated version of your code with these problems fixed:

```
document.ready = function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
    var options = new Array();
    var firstyear = (new Date().getFullYear()) - 17;

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var date = firstyear - i;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = date;
        el.value = date;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```